# Editing someone's answer

Tags: discussion

I see several answers that seem like a mixture of a straightforward, probably correct answer, with a very loosely related semi-rant at attorney's, judges, and courts. Is it within the etiquette of the site for a third party to edit out the semi-rant and therefore improve the answer and the tone of this site for future readers?

Comment: By coincidence, a post by the same person prompted my question.  I agree with one of the answers you received about editing out the irrelevant text in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

An interpretation of the site's [Be Nice](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) policy and the site's [What if I see someone doing something bad](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/flagging) policy:

- Edit would change the substantive content or primary purpose of the post: flag it instead
- Edit wouldn't change the substantive content or primary purpose of the post: attempt an edit, clearly explaining the reason for it. Posts, of course, may be re-edited in the event someone disagrees.

Comment: Explain the reason in the edited post or in a comment or in the box that pops up asking for a characterization for the edits? I

Comment: If it's a minor edit, the edit-characterization box should suffice.